# How to activate undo button for previous 4 actions in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rscript, rshiny

I am creating a R shiny app with buttons like browse, SpitColumn, deleting rows, values, and columns. Everything functions as it should. I have included a "undo" button, but I'm not sure how to make it work in the server function, also how to undo the previous four actions.

Could someone please assist me?

**csv data**

```
ID  Type   Range
21  A1 B1   100
22  C1 D1   200
23  E1 F1   300
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(DT)
library(tibble)


###function for deleting the rows
splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}
###_______________________________________________
### function for inserting a new column

fillvalues <- function(data, values, columName){
  df_fill <- data
  vec <- strsplit(values, ",")[[1]]
  df_fill <- tibble::add_column(df_fill, newcolumn = vec, .after = columName)
  df_fill
}

##function for removing the colum

removecolumn <- function(df, nameofthecolumn){
  df[ , -which(names(df) %in% nameofthecolumn)]
}

### use a_splitme.csv for testing this program

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
      uiOutput("selectUI"),
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows"),
      textInput("textbox", label="Input the value to replace:"),
      actionButton("replacevalues", label = 'Replace values'),
      actionButton("removecolumn", "Remove Column"),
      actionButton("Undo", 'Undo')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
  })
  
  output$selectUI<-renderUI({
    req(rv$data)
    selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', choices = names(rv$data))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    rv$data
  })
  observeEvent(input$replacevalues, {
    rv$data <- fillvalues(rv$data, input$textbox, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  observeEvent(input$removecolumn, {
    rv$data <- removecolumn(rv$data,input$selectcolumn)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the original file you read in as a separate `reactiveValues` object and assign it to `rv$data` when the `Undo` button is pressed.  Try this

```
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL, orig=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$orig <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
  
  output$selectUI<-renderUI({
    req(rv$data)
    selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', choices = names(rv$data))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    rv$data
  })
  observeEvent(input$replacevalues, {
    rv$data <- fillvalues(rv$data, input$textbox, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  observeEvent(input$removecolumn, {
    rv$data <- removecolumn(rv$data,input$selectcolumn)
  })
  observeEvent(input$Undo, {
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
}
```

Comment: It should work anytime the button is pressed.

Comment: Please accept my apologies; my previous comments were incorrect; yes, it works just nicely. However, I want the operation to be completed anytime I press the 'Undo' button, such as Ctrl+Z. My expectation is that when I click only once, it should not perform all of the preceding processes.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this as a new question.  I am not sure I fully understand your needs.  I think I have answered your original question.